# MacBook Pro 2015 13" vs MacBook Air 2019 for Final Cut Pro X

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, final-cut-pro

I've been thinking about a switch from my current 2015 MacBook Pro to the 2019 MacBook Air. I use Apple's Final Cut Pro X and Logic Pro X very consistently, so having a smooth workflow on these apps is a must.

Current specs:
- 2.9 GHz Intel Core i5
- 8 GB Ram

Potential upgrade specs:
- 1.6 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
- 8 GM Ram

My current computer also has some issues with the screen and some of the screws on the bottom plate, which is why I've considered a switch. Do you think upgrading to the 2019 Air could suit my needs?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, a MacBook Air is not the best system for heavy users of CPU-bound applications like Final Cut Pro X and Logic Pro X. The primary reason for this is that the thinner chassis has less efficient cooling than a larger machine like a MacBook Pro, resulting in the CPU being more likely to throttle down to lower speeds more quickly when it gets hot.

If you can afford it, a better upgrade for your use case may be a 13" MacBook Pro but be aware that a refreshed model is rumoured to be being released this year, with an upgraded keyboard (the same keyboard as in the 2019 MacBook Pro 16" and 2020 MacBook Air).